# When exactly do magic item charges regenerate - can they regain charges in the middle of battle?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, time

For magic items with charges, the general description states the item will "...regain[s] XdX expended Charges daily at dawn." Does this mean there is a specific time (say, 6 AM) when the item will regain these charges? As nothing states these charges must regenerate after a short or long rest, is it possible for charges to regenerate in the middle of a battle?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, a magic item that recharges at dawn would recharge whenever the sun comes up.  (This time varies by time of year).  It would be kinda hard to arrange for a fight to happen right at that time because D&D combats tend to take time measured in seconds, but supposing a long battle, yes, an item could recharge during it. You could probably schedule it fairly closely with use of an almanac and a good (magical?) timepiece, or otherwise magic that said "hey yo 30s to sunup."

Comment: “Dawn” also depends on topography- it’s considerably earlier on a mountaintop than in a valley

Comment: _"This time varies by time of year"_ Adventures in polar regions would be so fun: "Next recharge in: 5 month"

Answer (score 4):

### The rules do not specify times so precisely, so it's up to the DM

The rules do not specify a particular time at which magic items regain their charges. Indeed, they rarely make references to specific times at all (midnight, noon, dawn, and dusk is it).

Therefore, it's up to your DM to determine when "dawn" happens. You're right that the charges are on their own schedule, so it's possible that "dawn" happens in the middle of a battle and charges are regained, but that's up to the DM to decide.